# `this` accessing object properties

Tags: javascript

```js
class Test {
  X = 'X';
  someFunc = () => {
    console.log('someFunc is called');
    //someFunc2(); // undefined
    this.someFunc2(); //works
  }

  someFunc2() {
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}

Z = new Test();
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('X')); // true
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc')); // true
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2')); // false

Z.someFunc();
```

I'm trying to understand when i should use `this` keyword, as far as i know it's used when trying referring/using some object property, but in the code above i tried to test is `someFunc2` is property of the object and it returned false but still can called through `this.someFunc2();`. So does that mean `this` keyword not for accessing object property?

Comment: documentation is always the best https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: The documentation said that `this` for accessing properties, but in my case someFunc2 is not property of the object

Comment: Specifically `someFunc` is a callable property while `someFunc2` is a method.

Comment: @DanielW. — `someFunc2` absolutely **is** a property of the object! It's just up the inheritance tree

Comment: @Quentin every method of a class is property of the class welp but how do you explain `hasOwnProperty` beeing false on the method-property?

Comment: @DanielW. Because it's not an *own* property but an inherited one (from `Test.prototype`).

Comment: @DanielW. you can also check `"someFunc2" in Z`

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks, learned somthing `console.log(Test.prototype.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2'));`

Comment: @DrfArch Don't forget that `X = 'X'; someFunc = …` is just sugar for putting `this.X = 'X';
this.someFunc = …;` in the constructor of the class. Using only the plain name, without `this.`, to refer to a property/method of an instance [never works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object).

Answer (score 1):

I think, `console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2')); // false` is not a problem with `this` in JavaScript. It relates more to function declaration.

```
someFunc = ()=>{
    console.log('someFunc is called');
    //someFunc2(); // undefined
    this.someFunc2(); //works
}
```

is an attribute which is assigned an anonymous function. Whereas

```
someFunc2(){
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
}
```

is a shorthand function definition. For reference:

```
class Test {
  X = 'X';
  someFunc = ()=>{
    console.log('someFunc is called');
    //someFunc2(); // undefined
    this.someFunc2(); //works
  }
  
  someFunc2 = function (){
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}

Z = new Test();
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('X')); // true
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc')); // true
console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2')); // true 

console.log(Z.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2'));
```

resolves to true!

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Methoden_Definitionen

My first answer, I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
  X = 'X';
  someFunc = () => {
    console.log('someFunc is called');
    //someFunc2(); // undefined
    this.someFunc2(); //works
  }

  someFunc2() {
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}
```

and

```
class Test {
  X = 'X';
  someFunc = () => {
    console.log('someFunc is called');
    //someFunc2(); // undefined
    this.someFunc2(); //works
  }

  someFunc2 = () => {
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}
```

---

**the difference is:**

In the first example, we used **function definition** but never assign the function to any attribute or property.  so when you trying to use **hasOwnProperty**, it finds that the no attribute or property of name **someFunc2** is available.

```
class Test {
  ....
  someFunc2() {
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}
```

in the second example, we are assigning an anonymous function to an attribute  **someFunc2**,  so when you trying to use **hasOwnProperty**, it finds that the attribute or property **someFunc2** is available

```
class Test {
  ...
  someFunc2 = () => {
    console.log('someFunc2 is called');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is on how arrow functions works,

Arrow functions dont have their own context, meaning their "this" keyword is the same as their parent function "this" keyword (or in this case the Test class) they both refer to the same context.

meaning when you initiate an instance of "Test" using the "new Test()", the "someFunc" will automatically inherit the context of that instance, while "someFunc2" wont, and will be inherited through the prototype chain.

You can confirm by using

```
console.log(Z.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('someFunc2'))
```

thats why you still be able to call it.

I hope this clarifies a bit of whats going on exactly.